# How to use Mockito to test an HTTP SEND in Dart?

Tags: dart, mockito

I am trying to use **Mockito** in *dart* to test out my API classes.

I created a `Request` in order to set information such as the headers (*user-agent*, etc).
I then use a MockClient generated via the `@GenerateMocks([http.Client])` annotation to `send` the customised request.

That's where it becomes complicated for me.
`Get` or `Post` requests (via the `client.get` or `client.post` methods) return a Response, which is easy enough to test.

In fact, the Mockito test example on the website is a few lines long:

```
when(client
          .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1')))
      .thenAnswer((_) async =>
          http.Response('{"userId": 1, "id": 2, "title": "mock"}', 200));

  expect(await fetchAlbum(client), isA<Album>());
```

I can't figure out how to  do that in the situation of a `client.send`, which returns a `StreamedResponse` instead.

The bits and pieces I've assembled so far fail to compile... I'm not even sure what to strive for.

```
  final client = MockClient();

  final http.Request request = RequestBuilder.build("testedRoute", 
    secure: false);
  final String expectedResponse = "some json we (might) get from the server";
  final List<int> expectedBody = utf8.encode(expectedResponse);

  final expectedAnswer = (Invocation invocation) {
  final void Function(List<int>) onData = invocation.positionalArguments[0];
  final void Function() onDone = invocation.namedArguments[#onDone];
  final void Function(Object, [StackTrace]) onError = invocation.namedArguments[#onError];
  final bool cancelOnError = invocation.namedArguments[#cancelOnError];
return new Stream<List<int>>.fromIterable(<List<int>>[expectedBody]).listen(onData, onDone: onDone, onError: onError, cancelOnError: cancelOnError);
  };
  // Use Mockito to return a successful response when it calls the
  // provided http.Client.
  // ***************
  // WHEN
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> streamedResponseFuture = when(
      client.send(request)
  )
 // ***************
 // THEN 
  .thenAnswer(
    // Future<StreamedResponse> Function(Invocation) answer
    (result) async { 
      // return http.StreamedResponse( expectedAnswer, 200);
      return http.StreamedResponse( Stream<List<int>>.fromIterable(<List<int>>[expectedBody]), 200);
    }
           );

final fetchResult = await APIManager().fetchThings();
expect(fetchResult, isNotEmpty);
expect(fetchResult.first, isA<Thing>());
```

Comment: If you're using `package:http`, instead of creating your own `Mock` of `http.Client`, you should be using [the `MockClient` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) that it provides for you.  It provides a [`MockClient.streaming`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient/MockClient.streaming.html) constructor for `StreamedResponse`s.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks! Now I have my tickboxes all green :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jamesdlin I got this working!
I was indeed going off course here, and here's the code I now use:

```
 test('returns an list of Things if the http call completes successfully', () async {
  var client = testing.MockClient.streaming((request, bodyStream) {
    return bodyStream.bytesToString().then((bodyString) {
      var controller = StreamController<List<int>>(sync: true);
      Future.sync(() {

        final String expectedResponse = "some json we (might) get from the server";
        final List<int> expectedBody = utf8.encode(expectedResponse);
        controller.add(expectedBody);
        controller.close();
      });
      return http.StreamedResponse(controller.stream, 200);
    });
    });
  // Run a send manually to demonstrate what the return is supposed to hold
  client.send(http.Request(HttpMethod.GET.toString(),Uri(path:"my path")))
    .then((value) =>
    value.stream.first.then((value) {
      final thing = utf8.decode(value).toString();
      debugPrint("******************** $thing *****************");
      return thing;
    })
  );
  final fetchThingsResult = await APIManager(client: client).fetchThings();
  expect(fetchThingsResult , isNotEmpty);
  expect(fetchThingsResult .first, isA<Thing>());
});
```