# Mock StreamedResponse with http package

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Using the [http.testing](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/http.testing-library.html) library to mock http requests that return Responses work. That's fine as in the example:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/testing.dart';

var client = MockClient((request) async {
  if (request.url.path != "/data.json") {
    return Response("", 404);
  }
  return Response(
      json.encode({
        'numbers': [1, 4, 15, 19, 214]
      }),
      200,
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'});
});
```

I'm also using http requests that return StreamedResponses, like:

```
http.StreamedResponse response = await client.send(request);
```

How could I mock these kind of responses using the http.testing library or maybe even with [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) or another package?

I have tried to mock it with mockito before but I haven't figured out how to do it.

```
  when(
    client.send(any),
  ).thenAnswer((_) async => MockStreamedResponse());
```

The previous code doesn't even seem to mock the send method.

and I don't even know how to try with http.testing library because I don't have a source to generate the StreamedResponse.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/testing.dart';

var client = MockClient.streaming((request, bodyStream) => ???);
```

How could I create a mock or a StreamedResponse instance for my flutter test?

Comment: the code you need is here. https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/dart-lang/http/+/refs/tags/0.12.0/test/mock_client_test.dart#30

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817258/how-to-use-mockito-to-test-an-http-send-in-dart